# How to get more caustics

Tags: transparency, glass, reflection, caustics

i was following Blender gurus most recent tutorial , and was working on a glass plane which had the following node setup

[image: a]

**This is exactly what blender guru had shown in the video and is showing results as expected but i want more caustics , i want the reflection in the plane to be more vibrant , how should i do this**

Comment: Cycles cannot render caustics, and it tries to fake it instead which doesn't look that well. You'll need to figure out a way to fake it yourself in the shader. I followed this tutorial which I was pretty happy with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmk09JJNKJU

Comment: For caustics try a different render engine like LuxCore.

Comment: @EricXue write that as an awnsere